# Saved edited macro not sorting

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a pivot table whose content can change whenever a Data Connection is refreshed.
I saved a macro to sort the last column from largest to smallest and then edited it so that when it is run it always jumps to the last column.

But for some reason it is not sorting all the new refreshed data.

Can you help me sorting what might be happening, please?

Thank you

```
    Sub WarningsSort()
'
' WarningsSort Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("WARNINGS").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
    End With
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable").PivotFields( _
        "[Warnings].[Column5].[Column5]").AutoSort xlDescending, _
        "[Measures].[Count of Column5]", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(5), 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I think its just that its not refreshing the data. can you try refreshing "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll"

Comment: I would rather not do that because I will get a prompt for the Data files. I was aiming to manually starting the macro (with a button) after I refreshed the data. Does this make sense?